# R,S,V ECDSA packet signatures

Tags: cryptography, rlpx

I am using BouncyCastle to generate .NET core packet signatures. I want to be able to get the *v value* for the Ethereum signature.

To these ends, and with my understanding of the meaning of the *v value*, my aim is to take the [source](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/b19e68a517e56ef08cd2e50df4dcb8a96ddbe507/crypto/src/crypto/signers/ECDsaSigner.cs) for ECDSASigner, modify it to a custom local version, and return the correct *v value* on the basis of the discovered X coordinate in that code.

What I don't know though is which of the values 27..30 (27..28 in Ethereum yellow paper), correspond to which of the possible outputs. Is eg: 27==positive Y for given X?

Also, btw where is this stuff documented? YellowPaper.io refers to "The Literature" but where?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. Basically this code from the bitcoin core libraries define the v value

> *recid = (overflow ? 2 : 0) | (secp256k1_fe_is_odd(&r.y) ? 1 : 0);

That gets added to 27 for Ethereum, while 29 and 30 are invalid according to YellowPaper.io

Comment: Please note that if an implementation supports [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md), instead of using 27 or 28, it uses CHAIN_ID* 2 + 35. So the value of "v" can also be 37 or 38

Comment: Thanks. Also, to add, it seems the v value definition comes from the sec specification for compressing points to octet strings http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf (section 2.3.3)